# OWASP ZAP Ajax Spider URL parameter issue

Tags: web-crawler, owasp, zap

I'm trying to use ZAP to do an AJAX Spider on my web app and am trying to understand a couple of things.

1. When running the AJAX spider, it hits a URL structure of `mydomain.com/profile` and the spider gets stuck here and keeps hitting `mydomain.com/profile?1` then `profile?2`, `profile?3`, etc. It's an endless loop that displays all the same data. How do I prevent this? I tried marking it as a Data-Driven node but I'm not sure I have it set up right.
2. Can anyone explain exactly what `Maximum Crawl States` does? I tried using this to combat the issue above, but no luck.

Thanks!